# Get if user has enabled location via network

Tags: android, location

Some devices (or maybe all) allow user to hide his location using networks (wifi or data).
How to know if this setting has been enabled or disabled?

I need to get the current user location via gps (if enabled) or via wifi or data network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LocationManager holds those information:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean isNetworkdEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to check if user has location gps or network provider enabled:

```
private static LocationManager sLocationManager =
    (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

public static boolean isLocationProviderEnabled() {
    if (sLocationManager != null) {
        boolean gpsEnabled = false;
        boolean networkEnabled = false;

        try {
            gpsEnabled = sLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            networkEnabled = sLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (gpsEnabled || networkEnabled) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```